# Query near location efficiently without searching through loop

Tags: javascript, json, regex, get

I have a JSON db ->

```
"cities_&_stops_lat_&_lng": {
        "24.5854":{
            "73.7125":"PLACE 1"
        },
        "24.5926":{
            "72.7156":"PLACE 2"
        },
        "25.2138":{
            "75.8648":"PLACE 3"
        },
        "26.4499":{
            "74.6399":"PLACE 4"
        },
        "28.612912":{
            "77.227321":"PLACE 5"
        },
        "26.9124":{
            "75.7873":"PLACE 6"
        }
}
```

say my current location is `curr_lat = 28.2190 , curr_lng = 77.6789`

I want to query nearby locations without looping through and finding distance from each.

Instead I want to query Say within **10km range** , roughly **1 lat** 'or' **1 lng** = **100km**(actually 111km).

So, **10 km = 0.1**

So, I will **restrict** my **query** in between -> 
  `curr_lat - 0.1` to `curr_lng + 0.1` i.e => `28.1190` to `28.3190`

Sim, `curr_lng - 0.1` to `curr_lng + 0.1` i.e => `77.5789` to `77.7789`

My query approach would be ->

```
this.$http.get("https://something.com/cities_&_stops_lat_&_lng/'+28.1X +'/'+77.5X+'.json")
```

it doesn't matter if something is after `1 & 5`, hence named X -> what to write in place of x to achieve that ?

it means if something is in Db as `28.1...` or `77.5...` it should get queried

Sim, i will query for rest possible combinations

Comment: What means 'Sim'?

Comment: @NetMage "Similarly" ?

Comment: How does `.get()` query a json database?

Comment: Why do you need anything in place of `X`? If you're just looking for approximate locations, 1 digit of precision is probably good enough.

Comment: @NetMage its firebase DB, queried through vue-resource

Comment: @Barmar i need exact url(string) to query , if i simply query 28.1 , it will give error as url wont match, but if can use 28.1XXX where XXX will be some regular exp indicating i dont care whatever it is in DB , the string remain valid

Comment: `\d` in a regular expression matches any digit, so `28.1\d{3}`. Is this some kind of REST API that treats the pathname components as query strings?

Comment: A pattern like this might not be right. Suppose your location is `28.0`, don't you want `27.9` through `28.1`? If you just use `28.0xxx` you'll miss all the `27.9xxx`.

Comment: Tht is why said i will query all possible combination .

Answer (score 1):

If it's processing the pathname components as regular expressions, you can use `\d` to match any digit. You'll also need to escape the `.` in `28.1`, so it will be processed literally (`.` in a regexp matches any character). And you should use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode all these puncutation characters properly if necessary.

```
this.$http.get("https://something.com/cities_&_stops_lat_&_lng/'+encodeURIComponent('28\\.1\\d{3}') +'/'+encodeURIComponent('77\\.5\\d{3}')+'.json");
```